# How to determine if a module should be imported into CoreModule or SharedModule

Tags: angular

In an angular4 application, given the followiing modules:

- ReactiveFormsModule,
- FormsModule,
- HttpModule,
- TranslateModule, (the translate module)
- AgGridModule.withComponents( [] ), (a table framework)
- DatepickerModule.forRoot(), (and in general modules of ngx-bootstrap)

Where is the correct place to import them: **CoreModule** or **SharedModule** ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

It depends on whether:

- these modules define declarable types: components, directives or pipes.
- shared module are used in lazy loading

If they define declarables and you want to reuse them it's better to import the module into `Shared` module. If they don't, put them into `Core` module.

If shared modules are used in lazy loading, then you don't want to create another instance of the service and should import them into `Core` module. Usually these modules have `forRoot` or `forChild` methods defined, like for `DatepickerModule.forRoot()`.

So, for the modules in question:

- ReactiveFormsModule - shared
- FormsModule - shared
- HttpModule - core
- TranslateModule - core (has services)
- AgGridModule.withComponents( [] ) - shared
- DatepickerModule.forRoot() - core

For more information read [Avoiding common confusions with modules in Angular](https://blog.angularindepth.com/avoiding-common-confusions-with-modules-in-angular-ada070e6891f)

Answer (score 0):

best way to import modules.  I hope you using page lazy loading.

**These modules should imported in Root/Core module**

> ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule, HttpModule,

**This is optional you can import in Root/Core incase you required in all pages other wise import individually in page modules.**

> TranslateModule()

**These modules can import individual modules of dependent pages.**

> AgGridModule.withComponents( [] ), (a table framework)
>   DatepickerModule.forRoot(), (and in general modules of ngx-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

and each root components and the root definitions should be placed in CoreModule or in AppModule ?

Comment: There is no any restrictions for that . This is purely based on where you require those modules. You can keep any of those two places